# toilet is constantly running water to tank but won’t fill

Tags: plumbing, toilet

My toilet is constantly running and water is pouring into tank but won’t fill and toilet won’t flush

Comment: Where does the water go? Is it flowing down the bowl, through the opening at the bottom of the tank? If so, check the rubber flap at the bottom of the tank. It should close and seal when not flushing.

Comment: To add to @Jeffrey's comment, when dealing with a plumbing leak or drain a good question to always keep in mind is, "Where is it going?" this will help a lot with diagnosing issues in the future.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. There are already  a  number of question on this site dealing with this. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What could cause a toilet to leave the flapper up and keep running?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/15959/what-could-cause-a-toilet-to-leave-the-flapper-up-and-keep-running)

Comment: Ok I replaced the flapper and that fixed the problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Get some food coloring and put a lot of it into the tank, you will likely see it ending up in the bowl. When it leaks into the bowl slowly, it just goes down the drain slowly without creating a "flush" action.

If you start putting the food coloring in next to the overflow tube in the tank, you will see it go into the bowl immediately, which means your fill valve needs adjusting so that it does not let the water go over the top of that tube.

If it is not, then when the coloring filters its way down to the flapper, that's when you will likely start to see it make it's way into the bowl. that means you must replace the flapper.